# Does != have meaning in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

It seems to be an equivalency comparison for some types, but not strings.

```
# 3 != 3;;
- : bool = false
# 3 != 2;;
- : bool = true
```

This is as expected.

```
# "odp" = "odp";;
- : bool = true
# "odp" != "odp";;
- : bool = true
# "odp" <> "odp";;
- : bool = false
```

Why does `"odp" != "odp"` evaluate to `true`? What is it actually doing? Shouldn't it generate a type error?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

you have experienced the difference between structural and physical equality.

`<>` is to `=` (structural equality) as `!=` is to `==` (physical equality)

```
"odg" = "odg"  (* true  *)
"odg" == "odg" (* false *)
```

is false because each is instantiated in different memory locations, doing:

```
let v = "odg"
v == v (* true *)
v = v  (* true *)
```

Most of the time you'll want to use `=` and `<>`.

*edit about when structural and physical equality are equivalent*:

You can use the [what_is_it function](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/ocaml-internals/) and find out all the types that would be equal both structurally and physically. As mentioned in the comments below, and in the linked article, characters, integers, unit, empty list, and some instances of variant types will have this property.

Answer (score 18):

The opposite for `!=` operator is `==` operator, not the `=` one.

```
# "a" != "a" ;;
- : bool = true
# "a" == "a" ;;
- : bool = false
```

The == operator is a "physical equality".  When you type  `"a" == "a"`, you compare two *different instances* of strings that happen to look alike, so the operator returns `false`.  While having one instance makes it return true:

```
# let str = "a"
  in str == str ;;
- : bool = true
# let str = "a"
  in str != str ;;
- : bool = false
```

Answer (score 15):

A quick explanation about `==` and `!=` in OCaml in addition to all the correct answers that have already been provided:

1/ `==` and `!=` expose implementation details that you really don't want to know about. Example:

```
# let x = Some [] ;;
val x : 'a list option = Some []
# let t = Array.create 1 x ;;
val t : '_a list option array = [|Some []|]
# x == t.(0) ;;
- : bool = true
```

So far, so good: `x` and `t.(0)` are physically equal because `t.(0)` contains a pointer to the same block that `x` is pointing to. This is what basic knowledge of the implementation dictates. BUT:

```
# let x = 1.125 ;;
val x : float = 1.125
# let t = Array.create 1 x ;;
val t : float array = [|1.125|]
# x == t.(0) ;;
- : bool = false
```

What you are seeing here are the results of an otherwise useful optimization involving floats.

2/ On the other hand, there is a safe way to use `==`, and that is as a quick but incomplete way to check for structural equality.

If you are writing an equality function on binary trees

```
let equal t1 t2 =
  match ...
```

checking `t1` and `t2` for physical equality is a quick way to detect that they are obviously structurally equal, without even having to recurse and read them. That is:

```
let equal t1 t2 =
  if t1 == t2
  then true
  else 
    match ...
```

And if you keep in mind that in OCaml the “boolean or” operator is “lazy”,

```
let equal t1 t1 =
  (t1 == t2) ||
  match ...
```

Answer (score 2):

They are like two "Tom"s in your class! Because:

In this case, `"odp" = "odp"`
because they are **TWO** strings with **SAME** VALUE!!

So they are not `==` because they are **TWO** different strings store in **different** (Memory) **location**

They are `=` because they have the **identical string value**.

One more step deeper, "odp" is anonymous variable. And two anonymous variable leads to this **Two** strings.

For your convenience:

```
# "odp" = "odp";; 
- : bool = true 
# "odp" != "odp";; 
- : bool = true 
# "odp" <> "odp";; 
- : bool = false
```

Answer (score 1):

ints are the only type where physical and structural equality are the same, because ints are the only type that is unboxed

Comment: ints and chars are the only types... FTFY

Comment: To shorten this list up, it really should say anything integer like, as it also includes empty lists and unit

Comment: ...and anything that has been hash consed. That is done precisely so you can replace structural equality with physical equality to improve performance.