# Unexpected results with OCaml !=

Tags: ocaml, equality

From what I can tell, = and != is supposed to work on strings in OCaml.  I'm seeing strange results though which I would like to understand better.

When I compare two strings with = I get the results I expect:

```
# "steve" = "steve";;
- : bool = true
# "steve" = "rowe";;
- : bool = false
```

but when I try != I do not:

```
# "steve" != "rowe";;
- : bool = true
# "steve" != "steve";; (* unexpected - shouldn't this be false? *)
- : bool = true
```

Can anyone explain?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`!=` is not the negation of `=`. `<>` is the negation of `=` that you should use:

```
# "steve" <> "rowe" ;;
- : bool = true
# "steve" <> "steve" ;;
- : bool = false
#
```

`!=` is the negation of `==`, and if you are an OCaml beginner, you should not be using any of these two yet. They can be a little tricky, and they are officially underspecified (the only guarantee is that if two values are `==` they are `=`).

Comment: A question awhile ago covers some subtleties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412668/does-have-meaning-in-ocaml