# OCaml boolean expression [[]] == [[]]

Tags: list, boolean, ocaml, expression

I have a function that return `[[]]`, and I want to test the result as unit test.
But I found that the expression `[[]] == [[]]` return `false`.
Here a simple test code:

```
# [[]] == [[]];;
- : bool = false
```

Can someone explain me why this expression is evaluated as false?

Thanks.

Comment: There is more information on structural and physical equality in another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412668/does-have-meaning-in-ocaml/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `=` since you have *structural equality* for comparing two values:

```
# [[]] = [[]];;
- : bool = true
```

Because `==` is *reference equality*, it only returns true if you refer to the same memory location:

```
let a = [[]]
let b = a

# b == a;;
- : bool = true
```

Answer (score 9):

The `==` operator in OCaml means "physical equality". However, you have two (physically) different lists. Probably, you want "structural equality", which is tested by `=`.

Comment: Ok I undertstand now. But it means that the first [[]] is 'a list list and the second 'b list list ?

Comment: Yes, each `[]` allocates a new list (c.f. http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~scott/pl/lectures/caml-intro.html), but both list are not the *very same* list.

Comment: `[]` has structural and physical equality (it's integer-like). It does not allocate a new list. It's the outer brackets that are creating the new list, since, `[[]] = ([] :: [])`.

Comment: @nlucaroni: Actually, I referred to the outer brackets.  Thank you to clear this point.