# OCaml recursive function

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, eval, ocaml, reduce

I'm new in OCaml. I wrote this code to reduce algebraic expressions:

```
type expr =
    | Int of int
    | Float of float
    | Add of expr*expr
    | Sub of expr*expr
    | Mult of expr*expr
    | Div of expr*expr
    | Minus of expr

let rec eval expression = match expression with
    | Add (e1, e2) -> (eval e1) +. (eval e2)
    | Sub (e1,e2) -> (eval e1) -. (eval e2)
    | Mult (e1,e2) -> (eval e1) *. (eval e2)
    | Div (e1, e2) -> (eval e1) /. (eval e2)
    | Minus (e1) -> -.(eval e1)
    | Int i -> (float) i
    | Float f -> f

let rec simplify_expr e = match e with
| Add (e1,e2) -> if (eval e1) == 0.0 then simplify_expr e2 
                                    else if (eval e2) == 0.0 then simplify_expr e1 
                                    else Add (simplify_expr e1, simplify_expr e2)
| Mult(e1,e2) -> if (eval e1) == 1.0 then simplify_expr e2 
                                    else if (eval e2) == 1.0 then simplify_expr e1 
                                    else Mult (simplify_expr e1, simplify_expr e2)
| Sub (e1, e2) -> if (eval e1) == 0.0 then simplify_expr e2 
                                    else if (eval e2) == 0.0 then simplify_expr e1 
                                    else Sub (simplify_expr e1, simplify_expr e2)
| Div (e1, e2) -> if (eval e1) == 1.0 then simplify_expr e2 
                                    else if (eval e2) == 1.0 then simplify_expr e1 
                                    else Div (simplify_expr e1, simplify_expr e2)
| Int i -> e
| Minus e1 -> simplify_expr(e1)
| Float f -> e
```

I call simplify_expr in this way:

```
Expr.simplify_expr Expr.Mult (Expr.Int 4, Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0));;
```

And I've got wrong answer:

```
- : Expr.expr = Expr.Mult (Expr.Int 4, Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0))
```

Below I paste call's stack.

```
Expr.simplify_expr <--
  Expr.Mult (Expr.Int 4, Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0))
Expr.eval <-- Expr.Int 4
Expr.eval --> 4.
Expr.eval <-- Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0)
Expr.eval <-- Expr.Int 0
Expr.eval --> 0.
Expr.eval <-- Expr.Int 1
Expr.eval --> 1.
Expr.eval --> 1.
Expr.simplify_expr <-- Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0)
Expr.eval <-- Expr.Int 1
Expr.eval --> 1.
Expr.eval <-- Expr.Int 0
Expr.eval --> 0.
Expr.simplify_expr <-- Expr.Int 0
Expr.simplify_expr --> Expr.Int 0
Expr.simplify_expr <-- Expr.Int 1
Expr.simplify_expr --> Expr.Int 1
Expr.simplify_expr --> Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0)
Expr.simplify_expr <-- Expr.Int 4
Expr.simplify_expr --> Expr.Int 4
Expr.simplify_expr -->
  Expr.Mult (Expr.Int 4, Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0))
- : Expr.expr = Expr.Mult (Expr.Int 4, Expr.Add (Expr.Int 1, Expr.Int 0))
```

I have no idea, why after return of eval with 1 (9th line) simplify_expr was called with Add. Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 9):

Replace `==` with `=`. See for instance [Does != have meaning in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412668/does-have-meaning-in-ocaml) .

Not the question, but also check the `Sub`, `Div` and `Minus` cases of `simplify_expr`: `0 - e2` is not `e2` and `1 / e2` is not `e2`...